# Convert Batch file to Linux Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, converters

How to convert following batch file code to Linux shell script?

```
@echo off
set TOOL_PATH="C:\Tool"

set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05"

echo $: Starting Tool

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar %TOOL_PATH%\Updater.jar -config %TOOL_PATH%\config\config.properties
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

TOOL_PATH=/tool

JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_05

echo "Starting Tool"

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar $TOOL_PATH/Updater.jar -config $TOOL_PATH/config/config.properties
```

But you may have to change the actual paths.