# Need help converting batch file to linux shell script

Tags: linux

I am switching my server's hosting provider from Windows Server to Linux Debian and I need help to convert my Run.bat to an executable shell script.

The Windows batch file:

```
java -cp bin; deps/mail.jar; deps/xstream.jar; deps/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar;
deps/scheduling.jar -server server.Server
```

When I save this as a shell script it does not properly run when I "Run in terminal", the shell just opens and closes immediately.

Comment: [Possibilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164516/convert-batch-file-to-linux-shell-script)

Answer (score 1):

In linux, the separator is `:` instead of `;`, so try this instead:

```
$ java -cp bin:deps/mail.jar:deps/xstream.jar:deps/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar:deps/scheduling.jar -server server.Server
```

Copy the command without the $. The $ is used to indicate the command belongs in a linux shell.